# JPanel doesnt display the drawing

Tags: java, drawing, jpanel

I have problem displaying drawing on JPanel. I created three class which linked to each other as the following. I was wondering why this code, doesn't display my drawing.

```
c.add(pDraw);
pDraw.add(draw);
```

1) MAIN

```
public class mainPage {
    public static void main(String[]args){
      JFrame appFrame = new Frame();
      appFrame.setVisible(true); 
      appFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

2) JFRAME

```
 public class Frame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    private drawingBoard draw;  

    public Frame (){
         draw = new drawingBoard(); //generate pattern
         GridBagLayout m = new GridBagLayout();
         Container c = (Container)getContentPane();
         c.setLayout (m);
         GridBagConstraints con;
         .......

         JPanel pDraw = new JPanel();       
         pDraw.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
             .....  
         c.add(pDraw);
         pDraw.add(draw); // Call other class for drawing

         .....
         setResizable(false); 
         pack();
         setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
         setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

3) JPANEL

```
public class drawingBoard extends JPanel {
      .....
      public void paint(Graphics g) {
      ......
      }
   }
```

Comment: Without the layout constraints or the `paint(Graphics)` code this is kind of hard to debug.  Top of my head, `drawingBoard` is 0x0 in size due to a layout mistake; or your paint code is wonky.  Alternatively, have you debugged your code to confirm that `paint(Graphics)` is being called?

Comment: Thanks Kevin, you are absolutely right, I forgot to set the drawingBoard size :-) . The paint() method is working fine. Thanks again.

Comment: Should have posted as an answer I guess. :/

Answer (score 3):

Here is the answer, I forgot to set the size of the drawingBoard JPanel :-)

```
 public class drawingBoard extends JPanel {
        public drawingBoard(){
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension (500,500));

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a one line change to your code.

All you have to do is read the [Swing tutorial on "Custom Painting"](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) to figure out what you are doing wrong.

This is the third question in a row that could have been solved in minutes if you bothered to read the tutorial.

And you still haven't learned how to post a [SSCCE](http://homepage1.nifty.com/algafield/sscce.html), so I'm not about to spoon feed the answer to you.

Answer (score 0):

While it's a little tough to debug the code without seeing the GridBagConstraints or the paint() method, I will offer to you that it's generally considered better to override the paintComponent() method rather than the paint() method. In drawingBoard, try this instead of overriding paint():

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g); //optional
    ...
}
```

That may make a difference. For more information, [check out this article from Java](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/).

Also, as a freebie, you probably don't need to perform setVisible() and setDefaultCloseOperation() in both the main() method and Frame's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with all the points Ben Torell made in his post - plus some extra troubleshooting advice here.

Try this -

```
public class DrawingBoardTest extends JFrame {
    public DrawingBoardTest() {
        getContentPane().add(new drawingBoard(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args ) {
        JFrame f = new DrawingBoardTest();
        f.setSize(500, 500);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

If the drawingPanel shows up, then it's a problem with your GridBagLayout, or having a preferred size set on drawingPanel that isn't large enough to display the drawing, or adding drawingBoard to pDraw (which, as far as I can see from the code, isn't really needed...).

The default layout for a JFrame's content pane is BorderLayout, which will give all space to the center component, which is where I'm placing drawingBoard in the code I posted.

The default layout of a JPanel is FlowLayout, which will only give the component it's preferred size.  I see you set the preferred size on pDraw, but not on drawingBoard, in the original code - drawingBoard may have a preferred size set that is too small to display the drawing.

If the drawingPanel doesn't show up - then it's a problem in your drawingPanel paint() method.